# Pybind11, is there a way to bind a c++ class that takes integers and a double pointer

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

Using pybind11, I am trying to bind the following class and my code keeps failing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

extern double unifrand () ;

class PPermute {

public:
   PPermute (
      int x,
      int y,
      int z, 
      double **p
      ) ;
   ~PPermute () ;
   void do_permute () ;
```

I have tried the following but it keeps failing:

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
   py::class_<PPermute>(m, "PPermute")
      .def(py::init<int, int, int, double>())
      .def("do_permute", &PPermute::do_permute);   

}
```

Comment: `double` is not the same thing as `double**`.

Comment: i understand that but it also fails with double**

Comment: Why are you showing `double` (no stars) at all? What does it have to do with `double**`? It is utterly irrelevant. You could have shown `std::string` instead and complain that it doesn't work. Of course it doesn't work, it's not supposed to.

Comment: You also need to post a [mcve] including full unedited program text and error messages.

Comment: wow, you've been a great help. i couldnt have wished for better feedback